# after click event button color should remain same

Tags: android, button

I have two buttons..button A and Button B..I set background white for both..what I want is when user click on button A,background color should change black and it should remain black until user click on button B..

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#c53e2b" />
         <gradient
             android:angle="-90"  
             android:startColor="#a11005"
             android:endColor="#d62608"  />           
     </shape>

 </item>
<item android:state_pressed="false">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#c53e2b" />
         <solid  android:color="#e0341e"/>      
     </shape>
 </item> 
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#c53e2b" />
         <gradient
             android:angle="-90"  
             android:startColor="#ff6c52"
             android:endColor="#e0341e" />           
     </shape>
 </item>
 </selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the background color of the button in your your activity file.

```
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button1.setBackgroundColor(000000);

            }
        });
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button1.setBackgroundColor(FFFFFF);

            }
        });
```

Simply add 2 onclick listeners on your buttons and change the backgroundcolour of button1 if you click button1 and change it back if you click on button2.

Here are some sample XML buttons I used (you might need to change a bit):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/action_settings" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bg"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/action_settings" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using simply below code:

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                button1.setPressed(true);
                button2.setPressed(false);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add an activated state (`android:state_activated="true"`) to the drawable's xml and change another button's `setActivated(true/false)` on a button's click.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is you should create two xml file as mentioned above for on click event of buttons.

```
final Button b = new Button (MyClass.this);
b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.whatever));

final Button b1 = new Button (MyClass.this);
    b1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.whatever1));
```

Here whatever,whatever1 is xml file you created.

Another approach is to do,

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.onClick Listener){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setBackgroundColor(000000);

        }
    });

b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b1.setBackgroundColor(FFFFFF);

        }
    });
```